# Why does the docs for Kaboom.js say that the polygon function say it was added in v3000.2, but v3000.2 doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, kaboom

I was trying to make a polygon in Kaboom, to help with irregular shapes not provided by Kaboom in the regular shape functions, when I get an error stating that 'ERROR: polygon is not defined', even though it is clearly stated in the documentation

I don't believe I need to provide an example, but I will, just in case.

```
import kaboom from "kaboom"
import "kaboom/global"

kaboom()

add([
  polygon([vec2(0), vec2(50,0), vec2(50), vec2(0,50)]),
  pos(0)
])
```

with the following error

```
ERROR: polygon is not defined
    -> code/main.ts:6:0
    -> dist/game.js:4367:3
```

My biggest problem is that underneath the definition, it says

> `Since` v3000.2

in the documentation, even though v3000.2 hasn't even been published.

Am I missing something?

Edit:

I'm using replit to host and run my code, so that may be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work fine for me. Are you sure you have the latest version of `kaboom` installed? What does `npm outdated` return?

As for the `Since v3000.2`, it seems to be just an error in the documentation. Works fine in v3000.17: https://codepen.io/Latcarf/pen/qBwXEKo

Comment: I realized that my problem might just be replit, so, thank you for helping me